# How to extract a single file from a tar site backup

Tags: linux, tar

I have a backup of my site which is around 200GB(tar). I only want to extract a single file from this backup.

Any ideas on how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you can execute this to get a list of all filenames:

```
tar tf archive.tar
```

Then using this command you can extract only the files you desire

```
tar xf archive.tar path/inside/archive/a.txt another/path/b.txt
```

Note that you may need to use `z`, `j` or another option depending on whether and what compression you've used.

Comment: Note that these will dump out in the current working directory, matching the directory path inside the tar...  If you want to dump to a different directory, use `-C other/directory`, but that will still dump in the same structure as what is inside the tar... i.e. `tar xf archive.tar -C /dest/dir ./path/inside/archive/a.txt` will dump `a.txt` to `/dest/dir/path/inside/archive/a.txt`